# Passing Node objects into insert routine of linked list

Tags: python, linked-list

I've created a linked list class in Python, but I'm not sure how to enforce only passing `Node` objects into the `insert` routine.

```
# linked list in Python

class Node:
    """linked list node"""
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.next = None
        self.data = data
    def insert(self, n):
        n.next = self.next
        self.next = n
        return n
    def showall(self):
        print self.data
        if self.next != None:
            self.next.showall()


ll = Node("one")
ll.insert(Node("two")).insert(Node("three"))
ll.showall()
```

Comment: Use Python 3.4 `@singledispatch`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could delegate the construction of nodes to the `insert` function :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# linked list in Python

class Node:
    """linked list node"""
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.next = None
        self.data = data
    def insert(self, data):
        n = Node(data)
        n.next = self.next
        self.next = n
        return n
    def showall(self):
        print self.data
        if self.next != None:
            self.next.showall()


ll = Node("one")
ll.insert("two").insert("three")
ll.showall()
```

You could make this more concise by adding a default argument to your `__init__()` :

```
class Node:
    """linked list node"""
    def __init__(self, data, next=None):
        self.next = next
        self.data = data
    def insert(self, data):
        self.next = Node(data, self.next)
        return self.next
    def showall(self):
        print self.data
        if self.next != None:
            self.next.showall()


ll = Node("one")
ll.insert("two").insert("three")
ll.showall()
```

---

Additional point : from [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) :

> Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with `is` or
>   `is not`, never the equality operators.